# 2 Dimensional array and Print out average of the Columns and Rows

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Im still a beginner in C programming and I need a little help writing a code for my C programming class.

The prompt is: Input for this program is a two-dimensional array of floating point data located in a file named textfile94. The input array will contain 3 rows of data with each row containing 5 columns of data.

- I want you to use the two-subscript method of dynamic memory
  allocation.
- Use malloc to create an array that holds pointers.
- Each element of that array points at another array, which is the row of data.
- Use malloc in a loop to create your rows.
- Then you can use two subscript operators [r][c] to get at your data
  to do the summing and  averaging that the program calls for.
- This program calls for hard-coded height and width of the 2D array,
  known ahead of time (3x5, actually).
- Instead of writing in the literal numbers in your code, I want you to
  create a global constant variable to hold those dimensions, and use
  those in your code.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define int rows = 3;
#define int columns = 5;

float array[rows][columns];

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    FILE* fin;
    float x;
    int i,j;
    int* array;

    fin = fopen("textfile94", "r");
    fscanf(fin,"%f", &x);
    array =(int*) malloc(rows* sizeof(int*));

    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
            for(j=0;j<columns;j++)
              array[i]=(int*)malloc(columns* sizeof(int));
    }
    printf("The Average values for the three rows are:[%f]",array[i]);
    printf("The Average values for the five columns are:[%f]", array[j]);
    return 0;
}
```

In text file: 4.33 5.33 1.11 99.00 100.00 1.0 33.3 12.5 1.1 -1000.00 22.1 11.9 2.4 8.3 8.9

The program should output:
The average values for the three rows are: 41.95 -190.42 10.32
The average values for the five columns are: 9.14 16.84 5.33 36.13 -297.7

Having Trouble getting it to do this correctly, any help would be appreciated. I don't want the answer I want to learn from this but just need some hints. Thank you.

Updated Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 3
#define COLUMNS 5

float array[ROWS][COLUMNS];

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

FILE* fin;
int i;
float x;
float** array;

fin = fopen("textfile94", "r");
array=(float**) malloc(ROWS*sizeof(float*));
    for(i=0;i<ROWS;i++)
      array[ROWS]=(float*)malloc(COLUMNS*sizeof(float));
    for(j=0;j<COLUMNS;j++){
      fscanf(fin,"%f",&x);
      x = array[ROWS][COLUMNS];
}
printf("The Average values for the three rows are:%f", array[ROWS]);
printf("The Average values for the five columns are:%f", array[COLUMNS]);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'll see what I can add.

Defines are not written like that, and by convention should be all upper case

```
#define ROWS 3
#define COLUMNS 5
```

He wants you to dynamically allocate the array via malloc, you are now statically allocating a  2-dimensional array of floats and then you try to force arrays of ints into it. You should look up how to do multidimensional arrays with malloc.

Basically what you want is

```
float **array;
```

Now array is a pointer to pointer to float, then assign array rows number of pointers to float.

```
ROWS * sizeof(float*)
```

After that you can for each row assign array[row] with

```
COLUMNS * sizeof(float)
```

Now you have your array[ROWS][COLUMNS] structure

One approach to reading in the data in pythonesque pseudo code would be

```
for(row 1..3)
    array[row] = malloc(...)
    for(col 1..5)
        fscanf(value)
        array[row][col] = value
```

Tell me if I am being too vague, trying to give hints without giving the code.

Comment: Okay I think I understand a little bit better, I'm going to try that. I feel like I'm going in a circle lol with this code but not wanting just the answer is going to help me in the long run.

Comment: Im confused with the last part:Then malloc a rows sized chunk of float* assigning that to array and then malloc cols of floats to assign to that.

Comment: Yeah, I'll see if I can clear it up. But on the bright side, I just tested it and you are not far off once we get the pointers cleared up.

Comment: I added the size declarations for malloc since they can be tricky and I don't think they add much beyond having the skill to look them up in books/internet

Comment: okay so far i have added everything, do i need the for loop for the columns part like i have in my code? Also it says "assignment from incompatible pointer type" from this "array[ROWS]=(float**)malloc(COLUMNS*sizeof(float));" and i dont know what that means :(

Comment: you don't need to loop the columns. Well it means what it says, the types don't match. Now depending on what C standard you have... sigh I have been away from C too long. Well array[rows] is actually of type float* and on c99 mode I don't need casts at all. I'll check it out in ANSI mode and let you know within 15 minutes

Comment: ok, checked it, and under GCC I can choose to cast or not cast even in ANSI mode. if you choose cast it is (float**) and (float*) in that order

Comment: "array[ROWS]=(float*)malloc(COLUMNS*sizeof(float));"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4789/discussion-between-r-ahlskog-and-cka91405)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started on how to allocate the array, assign and access values, and then free memory. Error checking is omitted for clarity. Most likely you will want verify that `calloc` actually returns a valid pointer.

To complete the program you will have to read the values into the array and then calculate the averages.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const size_t rows = 3;
const size_t columns = 5;

int main(void)
{
    size_t i, j;
    /* allocate a two-dimensional array of zeroes */
    double **array = calloc(1, rows * sizeof(double *));
    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        array[i] = calloc(1, columns * sizeof(double));
    }
    /* print it out - replace this by reading in values */
    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
            fprintf(stdout, "%.2f", array[i][j]);
            fputc(' ', stdout);
        }
        fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    }
    /* TODO loop through the array again and average the data */
    /* free memory */
    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Its not to use calloc im suppose to use malloc and it is to be a float not a double

Comment: `calloc` and `malloc` are functionally equivalent, `calloc` just zeroes out the allocated memory for you, which is generally good programming practice. Changing `double` to `float` is pretty straightforward.

Comment: okay, i just kind of confused with it still i finished, the code ill update the new one.